# How to get the file name and show it on Qlistwidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to make a song list by open the QfileDialog to add the file .
Now I can play the song of list , When I click the item of QlistWidget.
But the item name is its path .
I want to show the file name on QlistWidget .
And when I click the item of QlistWidget , it has to transfer the path to `openaudio()` method .

Here is part of code :

```
expand='Image Files(*.mp3 *.wav)'
tips=open the file''
path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, tips,QtGui.QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QtGui.QDesktopServices.MusicLocation), expand)
if path:
   mlist.append(path)
   index=mlist.index(path) 
   self.ui.listWidget.insertItem(index,mlist[index])
```

Here is code of openaudio() :

```
def openaudio(self,path):
        self.connect(self.ui.listWidget,QtCore.SIGNAL('currentTextChanged(QString)'),self.ui.label_4,QtCore.SLOT('setText(QString)'))
        index=self.ui.listWidget.currentRow()        
        path=mlist[index]

        self.mediaObject.setCurrentSource(phonon.Phonon.MediaSource(path))
        self.mediaObject.play()
```

By the way ,how can I open multiple files at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be subclassing `QListWidgetItem`:

```
class MyItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        self.path = path

        import os
        filename = os.path.basename(self.path)
        super().__init__(filename)
```

And then connecting your `QListWidget` to your `openaudio(path)` method:

```
self.ui.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(lambda n: openaudio(n.path))
```

Apart from that specific question your code seems to have some other issues. Using an additional list (mlist) is not needed in this particular case:

```
path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, tips, QtGui.QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QtGui.QDesktopServices.MusicLocation), expand)
if path:
    self.ui.listWidget.addItem(MyItem(path))
```

and

```
def openaudio(self, path):
    # Do not do this here! Connections should usually be made in the init() method of the container!
    # self.connect(self.ui.listWidget,QtCore.SIGNAL('currentTextChanged(QString)'),self.ui.label_4,QtCore.SLOT('setText(QString)'))

    # Also take a look at the 'new' PyQt signals & slots style:
    # self.ui.listWidget.currentTextChanged.connect(self.ui.label_4.setText)

    self.mediaObject.setCurrentSource(phonon.Phonon.MediaSource(path))
    self.mediaObject.play()
```

Comment: Thank you!!! But I  have another "class StartQT4(QtGui.QDialog)" . It's used to connect ui . Like ,"QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)",            "self.ui = Ui_Form()","self.ui.setupUi(self)" . And when I click the pushbutton of ui , it will show the QFileDialog() .Therefore I can add songs to the QListWidgetItem. I am a beginner , so I don't know how to call the "class MyItem(QListWidgetItem)" and access virables of ui . Can you say more details ? Thanks!

Comment: The class `MyItem` is a regular python class that is subclassing `QListWidgetItem`. Thus you can use `MyItem` like a regular `QListWidgetItem`. Your listWidget can simply add them using `addItem(...)`.

I did not understand what your problem with connections exactly is, sorry...

Comment: When I call the class MyItem , it will show error that "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'" . Another error is that "'MyItem' object has no attribute 'ui'" . I don't know how to solve them .

Comment: This is the reason why we made it a subclass. We now have to give an additional argument, the path:
`MyItem(path)` where `path` is just a string containing the desired path to your mp3 file. This is what I have written in the answer:
`self.ui.listWidget.addItem(MyItem(path))`